# Get plugged/unplugged datetime of USB device using Windows registry keys

Tags: c#, .net, windows, usb, regedit

[image]I'm working on a software that takes care of extracting information about the USB devices that have been connected to the PC and to do this I'm using the system registry.
I would also like to try to retrieve information regarding the last plugged/unpluggedand datetime for that devices.
To do this you need to access the "Properties" subkeys (see attached image).

The problem is that to access it, **administrator privileges are not enough** and I could only do it by logging in as SYSTEM otherwise I get an access denied error.
How could I do this thing through c# ? Are there other avenues I could follow? Or is there a way to make the application run with even higher privileges than admin?

Comment: You can just right-click on the executable and select "Run as administrator".  You can also [tell Windows to always run it as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator).  Does this answer your question?

Comment: No. An Administrator account has not enought privileges.
For example: under "Properties" key there are othere subkeys that Administrator account can't see but only SYSTEM account can.